# Flatpick Selected Day Background and Border Color

Tags: flatpickr

I am working with Flatpickr in a SvelteKit project and applying custom styles. I've figured out how to change a number of different color but cannot find the selected day property. For example when I hover over a date I used the following.

```
:global(.flatpickr-day:hover) {
        @apply border-app-primaryAccent;
        @apply bg-app-primaryAccent;
    }
```

What is the .flatpickr-day:hover equivalent for the selected day in Flatpickr?